# Выражение "сыр-бор": откуда пошло и как правильно пишется?

Tags: этимология, орфография

Интересно, какая этимология выражения "сыр(-)бор"? И как оно правильно пишется: слитно, через дефис или раздельно?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Говорят "**сыр-бор**" (сырой бор), когда либо как снег на голову навалится большая беда, либо поднимется много шума из ничего. А при чем же здесь сосновый лес?
Дело, наверное, в том, что не было, да и нет у человека и зверя большей беды, чем пожар в лесу, когда меркнет солнце и тонет в непроглядном дыму вся лесная красота. Огонь ничего и никого не щадит. Кто был свидетелем подобных огненных ураганов, не забудет об этом никогда.
Остается только удивляться, как можно сравнивать в разговорной речи такое несчастье, такую огромную беду с пустяковой сутолокой, шумом и гамом. Разгадать загадку поможет пословица, от которой и пошло это выражение: «Разгорелся сыр-бор из-за сосенки» (то есть одна загоревшаяся сосенка — совсем малость, ерунда — стала причиной большой беды).

Толкование словосочетания **сыр-бо**р из Грамоты.ру:
*Сыр-бор загорелся из-за (от) кого, чего*. «Начался переполох, затеялось шумное дело». Исконно выражения связано с большим лесным пожаром. Оборот представляет собой сокращение пословичного выражения *Загорелся сыр-бор из-за сосенки* или *От искры сыр-бор загорелся* «большая беда может возникать из-за мелочей, из-за пустяков».

Answer (score 2):

*Сыр-бор (где "сыр" - краткое прилагательное) - сырой сосновый лес. Лес, растущий на сырых, болотистых местах. В русском фольклоре, отмечает **Мокиенко**, горение сырого бора является символом гневных эмоций, а также - **ВНИМАНИЕ!** - любовного стремления мужчины. У глагола "**гореть**" переносное значение "**быть охваченным каким-то сильным чувством, в частности, любовью**".
Постепенно ассоциация с лесными пожарами **['загорелся сыр-бор из-за сосенки']** утратилась и осколок пословицы стали употреблять в разных самостоятельных вариантах:

- Затевать сыр-бор, затеялся сыр-бор и
     даже заварился сыр-бор.

А современное написание через дефис только подчеркивает: все давно забыли о том, что сыр - это на самом деле "**сырой**".*
[ссылка на полное `обозночение`](http://weekly.ua/pulse/economy/2011/06/23/172242.html)